# Promise with timeout calling a function

Tags: javascript, promise, automated-tests, cypress, timeout

I have a function below and I would like to set a timeout.
If the execution of this function exceeds 2 minutes, timeout and the next test flow follows.

Does anyone know how I add a setTimeOut inside my function?

**Function:**

```
function resWait() {
    cy.req(
      'GET',
      `${url}/transaction/acquirertrxquery?acquirerId=1&dateFrom=${actualDate}%2000:00:00&dateTo=${actualDate}%2023:59:00&externalId=${idExternal}`
    ).then((res) => {
      if (res.body.content[0].trxConfirmationStatus.description === 'Confirmed') {
        return
      }
      cy.wait(3000)
      resWait()
    })
  }
```

I would like to use Promise.
But I don't know how to fit the promise into my function!
I have this example. How do I make this promise call my function or work the timeout?

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

Would you help me?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Replace  `cy.wait(3000); return resWait()` by `return sleep(3000).then(() => resWait())` to use the promise. However that won't solve the problem of dealing with the 2m timeout

Comment: Bergi, i did'n understand. if I use your suggestion it will be infinite looping. It won't solve my problem. Do you know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather suggest you control the retry executions by a maximum number of attempts, something like the following code. It's easier and safer to control in this way than setting a promise timeout because the recursive exit is more explicit and less prone to errors. And you can set the number of attempts and the `cy.wait` time in a way that matches your desired 2 minutes

```
function resWait(attemptsRemaining = 10) {
  cy.req(
    'GET',
    `${url}/transaction/acquirertrxquery?acquirerId=1&dateFrom=${actualDate}%2000:00:00&dateTo=${actualDate}%2023:59:00&externalId=${idExternal}`
  ).then((res) => {
    const isStatusConfirmed = res.body.content[0].trxConfirmationStatus.description === 'Confirmed';
    const noMoreAttemptsLeft = attemptsRemaining === 0;

    if (isStatusConfirmed || noMoreAttemptsLeft) {
      return
    }

    cy.wait(3000)

    resWait(attemptsRemaining - 1)
  })
}
```

Comment: Hugo Sangaletti, It worked out!
I used your suggestion and it solved my problem!
Thank you very much!!!!